# How to write out JSON data in Java using javax.json.*?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON data :

```
{
 "URLs":[
         {"URL":"http://www.yahoo.com" , "Size":"304" , "Requests":"1"},
         {"URL":"http://www.ibm.com" , "Size":"49358" , "Requests":"23"}
        ],
 "Total_Size":"49662",
 "Total_Requests":"24"
}
```

My code looks like this :

```
long totalSize=0,totalRequests=0;
String jsonArray="{\r\n"+
                 " \"URLs\":[\r\n";
for (int i=0;i<urlSizeRunner.length;i++)
{
  jsonArray+="         {\"URL\":\""+urlSizeRunner[i].aUrl+"\" , \"Size\":\""+urlSizeRunner[i].size+"\" , \"Requests\":\""+urlSizeRunner[i].requests+"\"}"+(i<urlSizeRunner.length-1?",":"")+"\r\n";
  totalSize+=urlSizeRunner[i].size;
  totalRequests+=urlSizeRunner[i].requests;
}
jsonArray+="        ],"+
           "\r\n \"Total_Size\":\""+totalSize+"\",\r\n \"Total_Requests\":\""+totalRequests+"\"\r\n}";
```

It writes out data in the right format, but I wonder how to do it using javax.json.*, something like : Json.createObjectBuilder().add(...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example (not exact solution):

```
    String[] urls = new String[] {"http://example1.com", "http://example2.com"};
    JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for (String url : urls) {
         builder.add(
             Json.createObjectBuilder().add("URL", url)
         );
    }
    final JsonObjectBuilder json = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    json.add("URLs", builder.build())
        .add("Total_Size", "12345");

    JsonObject out = json.build();
```

EDIT: updated to use dynamic number of urls.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach, but I couldn't figure out how to loop through all the Urls, what if I have 500 Urls, or what if during time of programming I don't know how many Urls there will be, so I need to use a loop or iterator, and what I need help most is how to do what you are doing but use a loop to build multiple Urls ?